# What is NSNumberFormatter adding elipsis?

Tags: nsnumberformatter

I recently added a method to the object that takes care of scoring to a game I'm working on to return a string using NSNumberFormatter. I've just received a score of `163,930,640`, and it is displayed this way in one place. But in another place, on a text label, it is displayed as `163,930,6...`. I'm pretty sure all digits were displayed during active game play, but it switched to having an elipsis when it stopped being updated. Here is how I create the label:

```
self.scoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
self.scoreLabel.hidden = YES;
self.scoreLabel.text = @"0";
self.scoreLabel.frame = [self scoreFrame];
self.scoreLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.scoreLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.scoreLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:36.0];
[self.scoreLabel setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[self.solutionBackgroundView addSubview:self.scoreLabel];
```

Could the problem be that the frame (set to 200 in the method not shown) is too small? I could change scoreFrame to initialize with a bigger frame, but I don't know what a maximum value would be, so I don't know what an appropriate size would be.

How would I size it appropriately to accommodate an unknown size? The score is updated 10 times a second, so I'm not sure using sizeToFit would be the right solution. I guess since I'm using textAlignmentCenter, and the label is centered where placed, I could just increase the size. On the other hand, I will be adding a feature to move the label to a space that is more restrictive. In any case, what I really want to know is what is triggering the elipsis.

The format I'm using is `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle`.

Comment: This isn't an `NSNumberFormatter` problem, but rather a `UILabel` `lineBreakMode` issue. Either make your label larger, or the font smaller.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll set the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property and `numberOfLines` to 1. I'll also increase the width a bit. Thanks for directing me to `UILabel` rather than `NSNumberFormatter`. I was barking up the wrong tree. If you make this an answer, I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `UILabel` `lineBreakMode` issue rather than an `NSNumberFormatter` issue. The text is being truncated because your label is not large enough to display the whole text. Either make your label larger or the font smaller.